# Creating a Regex to remove consecutive whitespaces except for newlines

Tags: c#, regex, string, whitespace

I'd like to use a Regex to do the following:

- All whitespace characters except for newlines must be converted to a space (i.e. `\f`, `\r`, `\t`, `\v` will be converted to a space)
- A string can not have two or more consecutive whitespaces except for newlines.

  - Newlines are limited to two consecutive occurrences at most (i.e. `\n` is okay, `\n\n` is okay too, but `\n\n\n` is not allowed and should be replaced by `\n\n`).
- If a space is preceded or followed by a newline, the space should be removed.

Some examples:

```
space-space => space
space-space-space => space
space-tab => space
space-tab-space => space
newline-newline => newline-newline
space-newline => newline
space-newline-newline => newline-newline
newline-space => newline
newline-space-newline => newline-newline
```

The only Regex I could come up with so far was this and it's removing all consecutive whitespaces:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\s)\s+", "$1");
```

Comment: I think this is too complex to do in one regular expression. It is fairly easy to do in several steps.

Comment: I'm okay with several steps.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Seems to be working fine. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match any whitespace but a newline, you may use `[^\S\n]` negated character class. Or, `[\s-[\n]]`, but I prefer the first one since it is portable to other regex engines.

Now, you may use a regex that will match optional newlines to the left and to the right of 1+ whitespaces other than newline. Then, you may check if any of the newlines were matched, and if yes, omit the whitespace matched, else, replace the match with a space. Then, you will need to replace any chunks of 3 or more newlines with two newlines.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\n?)[^\S\n]+(\n?)", m =>
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups[1].Value) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups[2].Value) // If any \n matched
        ? $"{m.Groups[1].Value}{m.Groups[2].Value}" // Concat Group 1 and 2 values
        : " ");  // Else, replace the 1+ whitespaces matched with a space
var final_result = Regex.Replace(result, @"\n{3,}", "\n\n"); // Replace 3+ \ns with two \ns
```

**Details**

- `(\n?)` - Capturing group 1: an optional newline
- `[^\S\n]+` - 1+ whitespaces other than newline
- `(\n?)` - Capturing group 2: an optional newline
- `\n{3,}` - 3 or more newlines.

Answer (score 0):

A simple multi-step solution is as follows:

> All whitespace characters except for newlines must be converted to a space (i.e. \f, \r, \t, \v will be converted to a space)

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, "[\\f\\r\\t\\v ]+", " ");
```

A space is included in the above group.

> If a space is preceded or followed by a newline, the space should be removed.

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, " \n", "\n");
output = Regex.Replace(output, "\n ", "\n");
```

The above two could instead be changed to use `String.Replace` in the style:

```
output = output.Replace(" \n", "\n");
output = output.Replace("\n ", "\n");
```

or even to:

```
output = output.Replace(" \n", "\n").Replace("\n ", "\n");
```

> A string can not have two or more consecutive whitespaces except for newlines.
>   Newlines are limited to two consecutive occurrences at most(i.e. \n is okay, \n\n is okay too, but \n\n\n is not allowed and should be replaced by \n\n).

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, "\n\n\n+", "\n\n");
```

As an aside. If the system uses `\r\n` for newline sequences then suppressing the `\r` characters may cause unwanted results.